# How to toggle mat-sidenav in another component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to toggle side-nav(in the drawer component)by clicking menu icon (in the header component). I've tried using service; but the service state didn't share between these two components.

The demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11pdkj

Comment: The problem happened because that vscode didn't check html close tag and Angular didn't check this error in template neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides very powerful concept of `Input, Output`.
Please consider to use `Input, Output and EventEmitter`
with this all you can bounce event from one component to another component.

Please have a look on this [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kryhv?embed=1&file=src/app/layouts/layouts.component.ts).

```
// drawer.component.ts
export class DrawerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;

  @Input()
  openNav: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log('ngOnChanges', this.openNav);
    if (this.openNav) {
      this.sidenav.open();
    } else {
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
  }
}

// header.component.ts
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "Dashboard";

  @Output()
  open: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  clickMenu() {
    this.open.emit(true);
  }
}

// layouts.component.html
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <app-drawer [openNav]="isOpen"></app-drawer>
  <app-header (open)="navOpen($event)"></app-header>
<div>

// layouts.component.ts
export class LayoutsComponent implements OnInit {

  isOpen: boolean;
  navOpen($event): void {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    console.log('navOpen', $event);
  }
}
```

also use respective component lifecycle hooks whenever required.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `@Input` and `@Output` decorators and the `EventEmitter` to send event from one to another component.
I've fixed your code,
Please check it out:
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ganqv5)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by not setting the sidenav in the service but turning the service into a notifier when the sidenav needs to toggle. So when you click the button the service tells a behaviour subject to emit it's change to the DrawerComponent. This component subscribes to the behaviour subject in the ngOnInit. And toggles the sidenav when the service notifies the component of the toggle.

The following StackBlitz shows how I fixed your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgm4xn